# Dummy variable for distance interval

Tags: r, variables, distance, proximity

In my dataset I want to create dummy variables for identifying the influence of a variable within certain distances.

The distances should be:

```
0-100 meters

100-200 meters

200-300 meters
```

up to 1000 meters so all in all 10 dummy variables.

How do I do this

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

When I run a regression with the dummy variables, I can't get the interval 0-100 meters in the regression. It's left out. Any ideas on why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `cut` function:

```
x <- 1:1000
cut(x,c(min(x),100,200,300,max(x)))
```

**EDIT**

To get the 10 levels :

```
cut(x,seq(min(x),max(x),100))
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `cut(x,(0:10)*100)` to get the ten levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `recode` function from `car` package in `R`.

```
install.packages("car")
library(car)
x<-0:1000
y<-recode(x,"0:100=1;101:200=2;201:300=3;301:400=4;401:500=5;501:600=6;601:700=7;701-800=8;801:900=9;else=10")

Output: 

> head(y)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
> tail(y)
[1] 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

**Note:** You can manipulate the min and max for each category. For example, instead of 100 for max in the first category, you can write 99.999 depending upon your data structure.

There is also `ifelse` function which you can use if you have only few categories. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105651/generate-column-values-with-multiple-conditions-in-r)